# Indexing dataframe doesn't return the correct values, and instead returns the cumulative value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named `df_expanded` that looks like this. The key column is 'A' and the important indices for this question are 29-31 (this is a modified version since the actual dataframe is huge):

```
>>> display(df_expanded)
         A     C   Cl   Co    D     E     F    Fa     G    Ga    H    HW
index                                                                      
                                       ...   
2.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0   0.0   11.0  2.0   8.0   0.0  0.0    
2.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  4.2   0.0   11.8  2.4   8.6   0.0  0.0    
2.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  4.4   0.0   12.6  2.8   9.2   0.0  0.0    
2.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  4.6   0.0   13.4  3.2   9.8   0.0  0.0    
2.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  4.8   0.0   14.2  3.6   10.4  0.0  0.0    
3.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  5.0   0.0   15.0  4.0   11.0  0.0  0.0    
3.0    0.4  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  5.2   0.0   16.0  4.0   11.6  0.0  0.0    
3.0    0.8  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  5.4   0.0   17.0  4.0   12.2  0.0  0.0    
3.0    1.2  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  5.6   0.0   18.0  4.0   12.8  0.0  0.0    
3.0    1.6  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  5.8   0.0   19.0  4.0   13.4  0.0  0.0    
4.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.0   0.0   20.0  4.0   14.0  0.0  0.0    
4.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.0   0.0   21.2  4.0   14.4  0.0  0.0    
4.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.0   0.0   22.4  4.0   14.8  0.0  0.0    
4.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.0   0.0   23.6  4.0   15.2  0.0  0.0    
4.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.0   0.0   24.8  4.0   15.6  0.0  0.0    
5.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.0   0.0   26.0  4.0   16.0  0.0  0.0    
5.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.2   0.0   27.4  4.0   16.6  0.0  0.0    
5.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.4   0.0   28.8  4.0   17.2  0.0  0.0    
5.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.6   0.0   30.2  4.0   17.8  0.0  0.0    
5.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  6.8   0.0   31.6  4.0   18.4  0.0  0.0    
6.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   0.0   33.0  4.0   19.0  0.0  0.0    
6.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   1.0   33.4  4.0   19.2  0.0  0.0    
6.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   2.0   33.8  4.0   19.4  0.0  0.0    
6.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   3.0   34.2  4.0   19.6  0.0  0.0    
6.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   4.0   34.6  4.0   19.8  0.0  0.0    
7.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   5.0   35.0  4.0   20.0  0.0  0.0    
7.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   5.0   36.2  4.0   20.4  0.0  0.0    
7.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   5.0   37.4  4.0   20.8  0.0  0.0    
7.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   5.0   38.6  4.0   21.2  0.0  0.0    
7.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   5.0   39.8  4.0   21.6  0.0  0.0    
8.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0   5.0   41.0  4.0   22.0  0.0  0.0    
8.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.2   5.0   41.0  4.0   22.2  0.0  0.0    
8.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.4   5.0   41.0  4.0   22.4  0.0  0.0    
8.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.6   5.0   41.0  4.0   22.6  0.0  0.0    
8.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  7.8   5.0   41.0  4.0   22.8  0.0  0.0    
9.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   41.0  4.0   23.0  0.0  0.0    
9.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   41.6  4.0   23.4  0.0  0.0    
9.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   42.2  4.0   23.8  0.0  0.0    
9.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   42.8  4.0   24.2  0.0  0.0    
9.0    2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   43.4  4.0   24.6  0.0  0.0    
10.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   44.0  4.0   25.0  0.0  0.0    
10.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   45.2  4.0   25.6  0.0  0.0    
10.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   46.4  4.0   26.2  0.0  0.0    
10.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   47.6  4.0   26.8  0.0  0.0    
10.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   48.8  4.0   27.4  0.0  0.0    
11.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   50.0  4.0   28.0  0.0  0.0    
11.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   50.4  4.4   28.4  0.2  0.0    
11.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   50.8  4.8   28.8  0.4  0.0    
11.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   51.2  5.2   29.2  0.6  0.0    
11.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   51.6  5.6   29.6  0.8  0.0    
12.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.0   52.0  6.0   30.0  1.0  0.0    
12.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   5.8   52.6  6.0   30.6  1.0  0.0    
12.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   6.6   53.2  6.0   31.2  1.0  0.0    
12.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   7.4   53.8  6.0   31.8  1.0  0.0    
12.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   8.2   54.4  6.0   32.4  1.0  0.0    
13.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   9.0   55.0  6.0   33.0  1.0  0.0    
13.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   10.0  55.4  6.0   33.6  1.0  0.0    
13.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   11.0  55.8  6.0   34.2  1.0  0.0    
13.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   12.0  56.2  6.0   34.8  1.0  0.0    
13.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   13.0  56.6  6.0   35.4  1.0  0.0    
14.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   14.0  57.0  6.0   36.0  1.0  0.0    
14.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   15.6  57.0  6.4   36.2  1.0  0.0    
14.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   17.2  57.0  6.8   36.4  1.0  0.0    
14.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   18.8  57.0  7.2   36.6  1.0  0.0    
14.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   20.4  57.0  7.6   36.8  1.0  0.0    
15.0   2.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   22.0  57.0  8.0   37.0  1.0  0.0    
15.0   2.0  0.0   0.2  0.0  0.0  8.0   22.6  58.0  8.4   37.0  1.0  0.0    
15.0   2.0  0.0   0.4  0.0  0.0  8.0   23.2  59.0  8.8   37.0  1.0  0.0    
15.0   2.0  0.0   0.6  0.0  0.0  8.0   23.8  60.0  9.2   37.0  1.0  0.0    
15.0   2.0  0.0   0.8  0.0  0.0  8.0   24.4  61.0  9.6   37.0  1.0  0.0    
16.0   2.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  8.0   25.0  62.0  10.0  37.0  1.0  0.0    
16.0   2.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  8.2   25.0  63.2  10.0  37.0  1.0  0.0    
16.0   2.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  8.4   25.0  64.4  10.0  37.0  1.0  0.0    
16.0   2.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  8.6   25.0  65.6  10.0  37.0  1.0  0.0    
16.0   2.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  8.8   25.0  66.8  10.0  37.0  1.0  0.0    
17.0   2.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  9.0   25.0  68.0  10.0  37.0  1.0  0.0    
17.0   2.0  0.0   1.2  0.0  0.0  9.0   26.2  68.4  10.4  37.2  1.0  0.0    
17.0   2.0  0.0   1.4  0.0  0.0  9.0   27.4  68.8  10.8  37.4  1.0  0.0    
17.0   2.0  0.0   1.6  0.0  0.0  9.0   28.6  69.2  11.2  37.6  1.0  0.0    
17.0   2.0  0.0   1.8  0.0  0.0  9.0   29.8  69.6  11.6  37.8  1.0  0.0    
18.0   2.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  9.0   31.0  70.0  12.0  38.0  1.0  0.0    
18.0   2.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  9.0   31.8  70.0  12.0  38.0  1.0  0.0    
18.0   2.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  9.0   32.6  70.0  12.0  38.0  1.0  0.0    
18.0   2.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  9.0   33.4  70.0  12.0  38.0  1.0  0.0    
18.0   2.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  9.0   34.2  70.0  12.0  38.0  1.0  0.0    
19.0   2.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  9.0   35.0  70.0  12.0  38.0  1.0  0.0    
19.0   2.0  0.6   2.0  0.0  0.0  9.4   35.2  70.0  12.4  38.0  1.0  0.0    
19.0   2.0  1.2   2.0  0.0  0.0  9.8   35.4  70.0  12.8  38.0  1.0  0.0    
19.0   2.0  1.8   2.0  0.0  0.0  10.2  35.6  70.0  13.2  38.0  1.0  0.0    
19.0   2.0  2.4   2.0  0.0  0.0  10.6  35.8  70.0  13.6  38.0  1.0  0.0    
20.0   2.0  3.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  11.0  36.0  70.0  14.0  38.0  1.0  0.0    
20.0   2.0  3.4   2.0  0.0  0.0  11.4  36.0  70.0  14.2  38.4  1.0  0.0    
20.0   2.0  3.8   2.0  0.0  0.0  11.8  36.0  70.0  14.4  38.8  1.0  0.0    
20.0   2.0  4.2   2.0  0.0  0.0  12.2  36.0  70.0  14.6  39.2  1.0  0.0    
20.0   2.0  4.6   2.0  0.0  0.0  12.6  36.0  70.0  14.8  39.6  1.0  0.0    
21.0   2.0  5.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  13.0  36.0  70.0  15.0  40.0  1.0  0.0    
21.0   2.0  5.6   2.0  0.0  0.0  13.2  36.6  70.0  15.4  40.0  1.0  0.0    
21.0   2.0  6.2   2.0  0.0  0.0  13.4  37.2  70.0  15.8  40.0  1.0  0.0    
21.0   2.0  6.8   2.0  0.0  0.0  13.6  37.8  70.0  16.2  40.0  1.0  0.0    
21.0   2.0  7.4   2.0  0.0  0.0  13.8  38.4  70.0  16.6  40.0  1.0  0.0    
22.0   2.0  8.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  14.0  39.0  70.0  17.0  40.0  1.0  0.0    
22.0   2.0  8.2   2.2  0.0  0.0  14.0  40.2  70.4  17.0  40.4  1.0  0.0    
22.0   2.0  8.4   2.4  0.0  0.0  14.0  41.4  70.8  17.0  40.8  1.0  0.0    
22.0   2.0  8.6   2.6  0.0  0.0  14.0  42.6  71.2  17.0  41.2  1.0  0.0    
22.0   2.0  8.8   2.8  0.0  0.0  14.0  43.8  71.6  17.0  41.6  1.0  0.0    
23.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  14.0  45.0  72.0  17.0  42.0  1.0  0.0    
23.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  14.2  45.6  72.0  17.6  42.4  1.0  0.0    
23.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  14.4  46.2  72.0  18.2  42.8  1.0  0.0    
23.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  14.6  46.8  72.0  18.8  43.2  1.0  0.0    
23.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  14.8  47.4  72.0  19.4  43.6  1.0  0.0    
24.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  15.0  48.0  72.0  20.0  44.0  1.0  0.0    
24.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  15.2  48.0  72.0  20.6  44.2  1.0  0.0    
24.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  15.4  48.0  72.0  21.2  44.4  1.0  0.0    
24.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  15.6  48.0  72.0  21.8  44.6  1.0  0.0    
24.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  15.8  48.0  72.0  22.4  44.8  1.0  0.0    
25.0   2.0  9.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  16.0  48.0  72.0  23.0  45.0  1.0  0.0    
25.0   2.0  9.4   3.0  0.0  0.0  16.4  48.0  72.0  23.2  45.0  1.0  0.4    
25.0   2.0  9.8   3.0  0.0  0.0  16.8  48.0  72.0  23.4  45.0  1.0  0.8    
25.0   2.0  10.2  3.0  0.0  0.0  17.2  48.0  72.0  23.6  45.0  1.0  1.2    
25.0   2.0  10.6  3.0  0.0  0.0  17.6  48.0  72.0  23.8  45.0  1.0  1.6    
26.0   2.0  11.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  18.0  48.0  72.0  24.0  45.0  1.0  2.0    
26.0   2.0  11.6  3.0  0.2  0.0  18.2  48.0  72.0  24.0  45.0  1.0  2.6    
26.0   2.0  12.2  3.0  0.4  0.0  18.4  48.0  72.0  24.0  45.0  1.0  3.2    
26.0   2.0  12.8  3.0  0.6  0.0  18.6  48.0  72.0  24.0  45.0  1.0  3.8    
26.0   2.0  13.4  3.0  0.8  0.0  18.8  48.0  72.0  24.0  45.0  1.0  4.4    
27.0   2.0  14.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  19.0  48.0  72.0  24.0  45.0  1.0  5.0    
27.0   2.0  14.4  3.0  1.0  0.0  19.4  48.0  72.4  24.4  45.2  1.0  5.4    
27.0   2.0  14.8  3.0  1.0  0.0  19.8  48.0  72.8  24.8  45.4  1.0  5.8    
27.0   2.0  15.2  3.0  1.0  0.0  20.2  48.0  73.2  25.2  45.6  1.0  6.2    
27.0   2.0  15.6  3.0  1.0  0.0  20.6  48.0  73.6  25.6  45.8  1.0  6.6    
28.0   2.0  16.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  21.0  48.0  74.0  26.0  46.0  1.0  7.0    
28.0   2.0  16.6  3.0  1.0  0.0  21.2  48.2  74.0  26.6  46.0  1.0  7.2    
28.0   2.0  17.2  3.0  1.0  0.0  21.4  48.4  74.0  27.2  46.0  1.0  7.4    
28.0   2.0  17.8  3.0  1.0  0.0  21.6  48.6  74.0  27.8  46.0  1.0  7.6    
28.0   2.0  18.4  3.0  1.0  0.0  21.8  48.8  74.0  28.4  46.0  1.0  7.8    
29.0   2.0  19.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  22.0  49.0  74.0  29.0  46.0  1.0  8.0    
29.0   2.0  19.2  3.4  1.0  0.0  22.0  50.0  74.0  29.0  46.4  1.0  8.0    
29.0   2.0  19.4  3.8  1.0  0.0  22.0  51.0  74.0  29.0  46.8  1.0  8.0    
29.0   2.0  19.6  4.2  1.0  0.0  22.0  52.0  74.0  29.0  47.2  1.0  8.0    
29.0   2.0  19.8  4.6  1.0  0.0  22.0  53.0  74.0  29.0  47.6  1.0  8.0    
30.0   2.0  20.0  5.0  1.0  0.0  22.0  54.0  74.0  29.0  48.0  1.0  8.0    
30.0   1.6  16.0  4.2  0.8  0.0  17.8  44.2  59.6  23.8  38.4  0.8  6.8    
30.0   1.2  12.0  3.4  0.6  0.0  13.6  34.4  45.2  18.6  28.8  0.6  5.6    
30.0   0.8  8.0   2.6  0.4  0.0  9.4   24.6  30.8  13.4  19.2  0.4  4.4    
30.0   0.4  4.0   1.8  0.2  0.0  5.2   14.8  16.4  8.2   9.6   0.2  3.2    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0   5.0   2.0   3.0   0.0   0.0  2.0    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.2   5.4   2.2   3.6   0.0   0.0  2.8    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.4   5.8   2.4   4.2   0.0   0.0  3.6    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.6   6.2   2.6   4.8   0.0   0.0  4.4    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.8   6.6   2.8   5.4   0.0   0.0  5.2    
                                       ...
```

When indexing this dataframe, I feel like `df_expanded.iloc[31]` should return the following:

```
         A     C   Cl   Co    D     E     F    Fa     G    Ga    H    HW
index                                                                   
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0   5.0   2.0   3.0   0.0   0.0  2.0    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.2   5.4   2.2   3.6   0.0   0.0  2.8    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.4   5.8   2.4   4.2   0.0   0.0  3.6    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.6   6.2   2.6   4.8   0.0   0.0  4.4    
31.0   0.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.8   6.6   2.8   5.4   0.0   0.0  5.2
```

However, the following is returned:

```
>>> print(df_expanded.iloc[31])
A       2.0 
C       0.0 
Cl      0.0 
Co      0.0 
D       0.0 
E       7.0 
F       1.0 
Fa      33.4
G       4.0 
Ga      19.2
H       0.0 
HW      0.0
```

Why is it that indexing the 31st index returns 2.0 for A (and the cumulative values for other columns as well) instead of what is shown when `df_expanded` is displayed? I can't figure out why it's working like this, so any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _I feel like `df_expanded.iloc[31]` should return the following_, is not the correct assumption. Use `df.loc[31.0]`

Answer (score -1):

```
df_expanded.iloc[31]
```

does not return what you expect because it return the 31st row in your dataset, you can check your 31st row, and that is exactly what you get.

For what you want, instead try

```
df_expanded.loc[31]
```